# Implement a long list of redirections in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I'm working on this Laravel project, ex : `https://project.com` and I have an Excel document containing more than 1000 lines for redirections that I have to add, as follow:

```
1- https://project.com/content -> https://project.com/new-content
2- https://project.com/news -> https://project.com/weather
3- https://project.com/pages/* -> https://project.com/
... etc
```

I need to redirect (redirection 301) each link on the left to the new link on the right. So I'm wondering if I need to just add all the data in an array, as key/value, and loop through it with an `if` statement for each entry. So everytime the user tries to access a link, he'll go through that loop

Is this the right thing to do? or there's a better/simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do it but reading from excel must be last way. Because excel has encoding and it takes time.

Read it from excel and put it to the database or Redis (Create a console command [https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#registering-commands] to do it one time). You can use it at middleware to check does URL have a redirect.

If you want it as a file try text-based files not excel. Also, you can use as config file as an array and cache it with `php artisan config:cache`.

Don't use if-else statements, use in an array or SQL query.

But the best option is with SQL query.

Comment: You think a SQL query will be better/faster than a hardcoded array in the code?

Comment: @mrhn It will, but I only have like 10 of those, I'll do them separately I guess.

Comment: @Görkem D. I'll also need a `if` statements, like : `if (request()->url() == 'https://project.com/content') {
            return redirect('https://project.com/new-content');
        }`

Comment: @dwix think of the query as the if statement, you don't need it

Comment: @dwix Model::where('request','{you can use like or = }',$requestUrl)->first(); if you have redirect it else pass. So php wont need to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through 1000 lines of hardcoded array on a get request is a bad idea, you can store these values in a fast key/value store like [Redis](https://redis.io) then fetch the value for the given URL as key and redirect accordingly

You can apply this in a global route middleware registered in `Http\Kernel`

Comment: But I'll still be looping through 1000 lines, that won't be a problem?

Comment: And how do you suggest I do that in the middleware, I'm still quite a beginner.